# Drawing 3D boxes on chessboard - OpenCV, LibGdx and java

Tags: java, opencv, libgdx, computer-vision, augmented-reality

I'm new to opencv. I'm working with it in java, which is a pain, since most of the example and resources around the internet is in C++.

Currently my project involves recognizing a chessboard and then be able to draw on specific parts of the board.

I've gotten so far as to get the corners through the Calib3d part of the library. But this is where i get stuck. My question is how do i convert the corners info i got (Which is the corners placement on the 2D image) to something i can use in a 3D space to draw on with LibGdx?

Following is my code (in snippets):

```
public class chessboardDrawer implements ApplicationListner{
... //Fields are here

MatOfPoint2f corners = new MatOfPoint2f();
MatOfPoint3f objectPoints = new MatOfPoint3f();

public void create(){
    webcam = new VideoCapture(0);
    ... //Program sleeps to make sure camera is ready

}

public void render(){
    //Fetch webcam image
    webcam.read(webcamImage);
    //Grayscale the image
    Imgproc.cvtColor(webcamImage, greyImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    //Check if image contains a chessboard of with 9x6 corners
    boolean foundCorners = Calib3d.findChessboardCorners(greyImage, 
    new Size(9,6), 
    corners, Calib3d.CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK | Calib3d.CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH);

    if(foundCorners){
        for(int i = 0; i < corners.height; i++){
            //This is where i have to convert the corners 
            //to something i can use in libGdx to draw boxes
            //And insert them into the objectPoints variable
        }
    }
    //Show the corners on the webcamIamge
    Calib3d.drawChessboardCorners(webcamImage, new Size(9,6), corners, true);
    //Helper library to show the webcamImage
    UtilAR.imDrawBackground(webcamImage);
}
}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You actually need to localize the (physical) camera using those coordinates.

   Fortunately, it is really easy in case of a chessboard.

   [Camera pose estimation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration_square_chess/camera_calibration_square_chess.html#pose-estimation)

   > **Note:**
   >   The current implementation in OpenCV may not satisfy you in terms of accuracy (at least for a monocular camera). A good AR experience demands nice accuracy.
2. **(*Optional*)** Use some noise filtering method/estimation algorithm to stabilize the pose estimate across time/frames (Preferably [Kalman Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter)).

   This would reduce jerks and wobbling.
3. Control pose (position + orientation) of a [PerspectiveCamera](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/PerspectiveCamera.html) using aforementioned pose estimated.
4. Draw 3D stuff using scales and initial orientation in accordance with the `objPoints` that you provided to the camera calibration method.

   You can follow this [nice blog post](http://blog.xoppa.com/basic-3d-using-libgdx-2/) to do it.

All 3D models that you render now would be in the chessboard's frame of reference.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.